# Modified Bessel function of the first kind with purely imaginary index

Tags: definite-integrals, special-functions, bessel-functions

I deal with the modified Bessel function of the firts kind with purely imaginary index, $I_{i\nu}(z)$, where $\nu\in\mathbb{R}$. I am interested in large $\nu$ expansion of this function. In order to find this expansion, I use the following integral representation, which is valid ([see 10.32.2](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32)),
$$I_{i\nu}(z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(i\nu+1/2)}\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^{i\nu}\int_{-1}^{+1}dt\,\exp\left\lbrace-zt+\left(i\nu-\frac{1}{2}\right)\ln(1-t^2)\right\rbrace.$$
In order to investigate large $\nu$ behavior, I try to evaluate this integral (I denote it as $J$) with help of steepest descent method.  I rewrite the integral as
$$J=\int_{-1}^{+1}dt\,e^{-zt}\exp\left\lbrace\nu\left(i-\frac{1}{2\nu}\right)f(t)\right\rbrace\approx \int_{-1}^{+1}dt\,e^{-zt}\exp\left\lbrace i\nu f(t)\right\rbrace,\quad f(t)=\ln(1-t^2).$$
So, I apply steepest descent for the function $F(t)=if(t)$. The integral saturates near the point $t_0$, which corresponds to a solution of $F'(t)=0$. This point is $t_0=0$. Next, I extend limits of integration to infinity and write
$$J\approx e^{-zt_0}e^{\nu t_0}\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{\nu|F''(t_0)|}}=\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{2\nu}}.$$
Then, I expand the function $\Gamma(i\nu+1/2)$ and obtain
$$\frac{1}{\Gamma(i\nu+1/2)}\approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left\lbrace i\nu+\frac{\pi\nu}{2}-i\nu\ln\nu\right\rbrace.$$
Combining approximated $J$ and this expansion, I write
$$\boxed{I_{i\nu}(z)\approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\nu}}\left(\frac{ze}{2\nu}\right)^{i\nu}e^{\pi\nu/2}} \tag{*}$$
Obtained expression $(*)$ seems right but I would like to be completely sure that my derivations are correct.

Comment: In general we can't discard $1/\nu$, that step is valid only because we have $f(0) = 0$. We also have to show that the contributions from the neighborhoods of $t = \pm 1$ are negligible. Then we need to find the steepest descent direction $\zeta = e^{i \phi}$ at $t = 0$, which isn't equal to $1$. Your answer (if you want to obtain an asymptotic equivalence) is missing the factor $\zeta$.

Comment: @Maxim could you please provide a good reference for it? My knowledge about steepest descent is very precarious

Comment: I'd suggest *Advanced Mathematical Methods for Scientists and Engineers* by Bender and Orszag.

Comment: You may be interested the paper [Asymptotics of modified Bessel functions of high order](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/268655814_Asymptotics_of_modified_Bessel_functions_of_high_order) by Sidi and Hoggan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for Max & Gary comments, I assume that below derivation is correct. I start from
$$I_{i\nu}(z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(i\nu+1/2)}\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^{i\nu}\int_{-1}^{+1}dt\,\left(1-t^2\right)^{i\nu-1/2}e^{-zt}.$$
Then, denote the appeared integral as $J$, so
$$ J = \int_{-1}^{+1}dt\,\left(1-t^2\right)^{i\nu-1/2}e^{-zt}.$$
The integrand can be represented as
$$g(t)e^{\nu f(t)}, \quad g(t)=\exp\left(-zt-\frac{1}{2}\ln(1-t^2)\right), f(t)=i\ln(1-t^2).$$
The steepest descent method gives
$$J\approx g(t_0)e^{\nu f(t_0)}e^{i\phi}\left(\frac{2\pi}{\nu|f''(t_0)|}\right)^{1/2},$$
where $f''(t_0)=|f''(t_0)|\exp(i\theta)$, $\phi=(\pi-\theta)/2$ and $t_0$ is a solution of $f'(t)=0$. It is easy to see that $t_0=0$. Then,
$$f''(t_0)=-2i\rightarrow |f''(t_0)|=2e^{-i\pi/2}\rightarrow \phi=\frac{3\pi i}{4},\quad g(t_0)=1, f(t_0)=1.$$
Considering all the above,
$$J\approx \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\nu}}e^{3\pi i/4}.$$
Next, I expand $1/\Gamma(i\nu+1/2)$ for large $\nu$ and obtain
$$\frac{1}{\Gamma(i\nu+1/2)}\approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left\lbrace i\nu+\frac{\pi\nu}{2}-i\nu\ln\nu\right\rbrace.$$
So, finally,
$$\boxed{I_{i\nu}(z)\approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\nu}}\left(\frac{ze}{2\nu}\right)^{i\nu}e^{\pi\nu/2}e^{3i\pi/4}}$$

Comment: Correct up to sign. In terms of the method of steepest descent, $\phi = 3 \pi/4$ means the contour goes from the fourth to the second quadrant. It's impossible to modify the original contour in such a way without going outside of the region $\operatorname {Re} f(t) < 0$.

Comment: @Maxim the sign in phase factor (I mean that it should be $\exp(-3\pi i/4)$ or the sign of whole expression?